# Using Odata Client to Insert Data into a joined Table

Tags: c#, ado.net, odata

I have a table called "Application". 
Application has (FirstName, LastName, Address, etc..) as fields in its table.

Application also has a Collection of "AcademicYears".

And "AcademicYears" has a collection of "Applications" which therefore automatically generated a joined table Application_AcademicYears.

In the following code that i am trying, i get an error:
"The context is not currently tracking the entity." (`service` is my Container)

```
  service.AddLink(ay.Description,"Applications",app.AcademicYears);
            service.SetLink(app.AcademicYears, "AcademicYears", ay.Description);


   service.AddLink(ay.Description,"Applications",app.AcademicYears);
            service.SetLink(app.AcademicYears, "AcademicYears", ay.Description);
```

My only purpose is to tag the Application with an Academic Year that is already picked by the User.

Any feedback on this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot To Mention:                                                                                            app is an object of Application /// ay is an Object of AcademicYears

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?